# Не устанавливается Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos7

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу установить Ubuntu на ноут.
Изначально была установлена Windows7.
При установке не видит диск sda как root, видит только загрузочную флешку (sdb)

Пробовала восстановить через boot-repair, вот логи:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SGq56w9n8s/

У меня получается главный dev/sda2, но при загрузке его не видно
Та же беда и при установке centos7 - мой основной диск не доступен для sourcse destination

Comment: Снести все разделы и таблицу разделов перед установкой - пробовала?

Answer (score 0):

Если ноут новый, попробуй debian 9 live dvd. 
Проблема связанна с тем что ядро используемое в Centos7 устаревшей версии.